# Clearing attributes set in JSON file

Tags: chef-infra

How one does remove attribte set in JSON data file (`-j` used during chef-client run)? Lets say, I needed to override attribute:

```
default['param']['myParam'] = 'A'
```

So I've created JSON file:

```
{
 "param" : {
    "myParam" : "B"
 }
}
```

In the next version of cookbook, this parameter gets new value: `C`. I'm removing it from JSON datafile and want to use this new value, but Chef stores `B` even when it isn't in JSON file.

How can I ensure that Chef will ignore old attributes?

Answer (score 1):

Attributes set via `-j` get put in the `normal` level, which sticks around until cleared. This is why we do not recommend using the `normal` level or `-j` attributes. You'll have to clear them manually using tools like `knife node edit`.

Comment: This JSON file is very elastic way to provide parameters for client (situation without chef-server, standalone cookbooks with chef-client only). Does any other way of providing attributes for client exist? I mean without editing cookbook attributes - variables should be set by client who could forget he is using Chef?

Comment: It is very convenient, but as mention it means values persist because once you set them, Chef doesn't know when to unset them. If you want a way to send info in to a Chef run that only matters once, you can use env vars or your own JSON file that you read and parse in recipe code. If you want something more long-lasting but adjustable, make roles. Long-term answer, if you have a system wrapping Chef, have Chef read from that (via REST or whatever) in your cookbook code.

Answer (score 0):

Your attributes will be updated once you run chef-client only. So run chef-client on node and verify the attribute value after that